# Batch Script: referancing variable not working

Tags: batch-file

I was making a script in batch for a larger project and my referencing of a variable would not work. I am not very experienced with batch scripts so this could be very obvious.

Here is my code

```
@Echo off
set /p input = Input freq: 
pause
:loop
<my code>
timeout /t %input% /nobreak
goto :loop
```

The timeout command seems to not be working, however, when i change the time value from %input% to a normal integer, the timeout command works.

Comment: You need to be careful of your spacing and use quotes. You should use `set /p "input=Input freq:"` Better yet, have a look at the output of `choice /?` to use that command instead.

Comment: Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG " to a value of " N".